# The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file in Load Balancer asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, windows

We are having a 2 App servers for which request will come randomly from the load balancer. we are using state server to store the session. We have an Excel upload feature in our web app while doing upload we are saving excel files in a shared location. let's say appserver1 creates the files saves files in a shared location and when we try to preview the files and request goes to appserver2 and appserver2 tries to preview the file we are getting the error ***"The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data***"
.if we are the doing the same process with the single server everything works fine.

Comment: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file" seems like your excel is connected to an Access database that is still used by another process. You can use procexp from sysinternals to check which processes hold handles on which files.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Fregger. The process which is currently using Excel might be in server1 and the next step can come from server2 since both will access shared location. it it possible stop process of server1 from server2?